# Facebook Login issues

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

recently Facebook has removed from iOS the possibility to open up their app to login and instead it opens up a web view to proceed with login.
I'd like to know how to prefill the web view with data taken from the Facebook app (if it's installed)

Comment: Facebook SDK will open web page only if there is no Facebook app on device. Otherwise Facebook app will be opened instead of web page.

Comment: It was like this a few months ago, now it will always open the web view